# How to use a for loop to display all numbers between 2 spinedit controls Lazarus

Tags: delphi, for-loop, lazarus

My problem is that i cant work out how to display all numbers selected between 2 spinedit controls.

Example:

```
SedValue1 := 5
SedValue2 := 7
```

How can i use a for loop to display the numbers 5, 6 and 7?

What i have so far:

```
for iCount := Value1 to Value2 do
begin
     lstFORList.items.add('Digit number :'+IntToStr(iCount));
end;
```

Preferably i would like them to be displayed like:

Digit number : 1(first loop) is 5.

Digit number : 2(second loop) is 6. and so on.

I hope this is enough to help me as im stuck where i am, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Given your existing for loop and variables, the digit number can be calculated like this:

```
1 + iCount - Value1
```

You know how to do everything else.

In my opinion `iCount` is a poor choice of name. This variable is a loop variable and not a count. If it were me I would name it `i`. Everyone knows that's the name of the loop variable!

Comment: On that note, is it acceptable that `i` stands for `iteration` or `index`? Or something else? Or all of the above?

Comment: `i` is for integer I believe and the convention comes from Fortran implicit variables or likely before. In older Fortran versions variables declared without explicit type were implicatly typed based on their first letter. So i to n would be integers. Anything else real. That's what I have always assumed. Maybe somebody even more old than I will correct me!

Comment: I think `i` comes from math, and is used frequently in formulas representing series. I assume it stands for `index`, but that is only a guess.

Comment: That's very plausible. I ought to know that really given what I studied at university....

Comment: Wiki confirms the thoughts on the naming convention of loop counters here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_counter .  I have been using ii for a few years as its easier to search for etc.  That wiki article also mentions this practice - and I thought I was unique!

Comment: @MichaelVincent Interesting read. Very small variable names `i`, `ii`, make perfect sense for loop counters since they are very localised and they are so prevalent that their intent is obvious from context. Once you start nesting loops though it can be clearer to use meaningful names.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes, I agree. I've been using "row" and "col" on some grid work I've been doing recently, much clearer when iterating through all the cells.  In previous employment I was working with seismic data in 5 axis (x, y, z and 2 computed axes) often with multiple processed versions.  i, j, k  weren't descriptive enough for me to follow the code. Regards,

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The code worked perfectly, should have seen it myself to be honest, but thanks and im glad my problem could start a nice programming conversation about loops. :)